# Pegar valores de json no retorno de cURL

Tags: php, json, libcurl

Estou com três servidores distintos: servidor A, servidor B e servidor C. Aonde A faz o cadastro de usuários e guarda informações pessoais. Estou tentando fazer login a partir dos servidores B e C em A utilizando cURL.

Preciso retornar os valores de A para autenticar usuário e tento fazer isto com um array e json_encode porém não consigo resgatar estes valores para armazenar em strings php nos servidores B ou C.

## PHP cURL

```
<?php
header ('Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
if(!isset($_SESSION)) session_start(); 
if(isset($_POST['name'])){
   $name = $_POST['name'];
}
if($name == "Fulano"){
    $postData = array(
     'name' => $name
);
// Initialize cURL
$ch = curl_init();

// Setup options for a cURL transfer
curl_setopt_array(
    $ch, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => 'http://servidor requisitado/login_ext.php',
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)',
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
    CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR => 'tmp/cookie.txt',
    CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE => 'tmp/cookie.txt',
    CURLOPT_POST => true,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $postData,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true
));

// Return web page
//return curl_exec($ch);

$server_output = curl_exec ($ch);

curl_close ($ch);

// further processing ....
if($server_output != ''){

   $string = json_decode($server_output, true);
    //???????????
   }

}else{
   echo "ERR!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!";
}
```

## PHP login_ext.php

```
<?php
header ('Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');

if(isset($_POST['name'])){
   $name = $_POST['name'];
   //Verificação no Banco de dados!
   $nameRequest = $fetch['name'];// Ex: Fulano!
   $sobrenomeRequest = $fetch['sobrenome'];

   if($name == $nameRequest){

      $json = array("nome"=>$name, "sobrenome"=>$sobrenomeRequest);

      echo json_encode($json);
   }
}else{
   echo "Err";
}
```

Já tentei fazer um foreach porém sem resultados!

Qual a sintaxe para recuperar e usar estes valores?

Comment: Aonde você quer pegar os valores? no "*PHP cURL*" onde você tem `$string = json_decode($server_output, true);` abaixo coloque `print_r($string);`, veja qual é a saída.

Comment: A saída é um json:{"nome":"Fulano","sobrenome":"Ciclano"}1

Comment: São estes valores que não consigo atribuir a uma string php...tipo ($returnNome e $returnSobrenome) separadamente.

Answer (score 2):

Uma forma de estar resgatando esses valores é:

```
$string = json_decode($server_output);
$nome = $string->nome;
$sobrenome = $string->sobrenome;

echo $nome . " " . $sobrenome . "\n"; // Fulano Ciclano
```

[Ver `demonstração`](http://ideone.com/22nLJe)

Comment: Este exemplo serve no mesmo servidor más o json do array vem de outro servidor por cURL ... um var_dump() nas strings $nome ou $sobrenome retornam "NULL"

Comment: @LauroMoraes Consegue obter algo assim: `echo $string->nome`? ou `echo $string[0]['nome']`.

Comment: echo $string->nome retorna erro(Notice: Trying to get property of non-object) e já em echo $string[0]['nome'] não retorna...fazendo um var_dump() nela retorna "NULL"

Comment: @LauroMoraes Estranho. Qual a saída de `echo gettype($string);`? Tem como mostrar um *print* desse comando: `print_r($string);`?

Comment: gettype da "integer" e print_r da "11"

Comment: @LauroMoraes Então é por isso que não retorna nada. A variável `$string` é isso `$string = json_decode($server_output, true);` **correto**? Tente acessar pelo objeto, vou atualizar a resposta.

Comment: Para as duas strings o erro é o mesmo Notice: Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: @LauroMoraes Deu certo?

Answer (score 1):

Se entendi corretamente sua pergunta esta forma vá de encontro com o que precisa:

```
// Pega o json decodificado
$jsonDecodificado = json_decode($server_output, true);

foreach($jsonDecodificado as $key => $value){
         $nome = $value;
         echo $nome.'<br />';
}
```

Checar se determinada chave existe no array:

```
if (array_key_exists("nome",$jsonDecodificado))
  {
  //faz uma validação;
  }
```

Estou percorrendo o array resultante da decodificação do json, feito isso posso imprimi-lo, compara-lo, fazer atribuições.

Comment: Bom não posso comparar, estou tentando "resgatar valores" e atribuir a novas strings em php separadamente e o exemplo retornou erro (Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'as' (T_AS), expecting ';')

Comment: Desculpe era um foeach ao inves de for, teste novamente.

Comment: Você entende o que fiz? estou percorrendo o array resultante da decodificação do json, feito isso posso imprimi-lo, compara-lo, fazer atribuições.

Comment: Pois como havia dito na pergunta já tentei um foreach e da este erro (Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() )

Comment: faça assim e veja o esultado: var_dump(json_decode($server_output, true)); veja se sai um array.

Comment: var_dump() em json_decode() retorna   {"nome":"Fulano","sobrenome":"Ciclano"}int(1)

Comment: se esta sendo retornado realmente `{"nome":"Fulano","sobrenome":"Ciclano"}int(1)` então o código é capaz de pegar os atributos.